# How long do transactions on the Liquid Network take to clear?

Tags: sidechains, blockstream, liquid

Transactions on the Liquid sidechain are said to enable much faster transfers than the main Bitcoin blockchain.  How fast are the the transfers?   Does it still use a blockchain?

Comment: This sort of comes across as spammy.

Comment: @Anonymous I see how one might feel that way, I just wanted to find the answer to this question and didn't find it here.  So I researched a bit and made a Q&A.  Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it still use a blockchain?

Yes, it is using a blockchain, however it is "federated" with a known set of participants which enforce consensus rules. It does not utilize proof-of-work mining.  The Liquid sidechain allows 2-way pegging of assets eg: `L-BTC` <-> `BTC`.

> How fast are the the transfers?

The [Liquid white paper](https://blockstream.com/assets/downloads/strong-federations.pdf) mentions 1 minute block times with the possibility to reduce this:

*"Today, the implementation allows for one minute blocks. It will be possible to reduce the time to the amount required for the pre-commit and agreement threshold time of the network traversal"*

However (as of October 29th, 2018) the [Blockstream website](https://blockstream.com/liquid/) has a bullet point indicating the actual settlement time is 2-minutes currently:

*"React to trading opportunities faster thanks to two minute settlement times when sending between exchanges."*

This should allow much faster transfers between exchanges which could potentially let users trade `L-BTC` upon receipt as though it were `BTC`.