# How does Blockstream's Liquid Bitcoin network work to make fast bitcoin transactions?

Tags: blockstream, liquid

Blockstream's Liquid network can facilitate instant bitcoin transactions on their network. How does it work exactly?

My main questions are:

As a user with BTC on some exchange that supports Liquid Bitcoin (LBTC).

- Is Blockstream Liquid like an exchange for exchanges that only exchanges use?
- How is the 10 min blocktime eliminated?
- Can regular users be on the Liquid Network and with what wallet?
- What is their roadmap if any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How long do transactions on the Liquid Network take to clear?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80497/how-long-do-transactions-on-the-liquid-network-take-to-clear/80498#80498)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long do transactions on the Liquid Network take to clear?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80497/how-long-do-transactions-on-the-liquid-network-take-to-clear)